# InstrumentationTestCase is deprecate in api24

Tags: android, testing, instrumentation, testcase

**The InstrumentationTestCase is deprecate in api24**.

> What could I use to replace keeping the same functions?

**Ex:**

```
// Start the MainActivity as the first activity...
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setClassName(instrumentation.getTargetContext(), MainActivity.class.getName());
    instrumentation.startActivitySync(intent);
```

I have read a few things about `InstrumentationRegistry`, but the functions are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Use class [IntstrumentRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html) and from its method

> **getInstrumentation()**
>   Returns the instrumentation currently running.

you can use any method like:

> **startActivitySync(Intent intent)**
>   Start a new activity and wait for it to begin running before returning.

**Edit:** This is instrumentation reference link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html

Comment: Thanks Sara, but how could I check if there was the correct activity change, which I currently use:  `currentActivity = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, TIME_OUT);`
        `assertThat(currentActivity, is(notNullValue()));`

Comment: Sorry , I did not understand your point? you are saying after using InstrumentationRegistry and above method `getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, TIME_OUT);` you are unable to achieve your goal?

Comment: I can achieve yes, but using `InstrumentationTestCase`, I would like to know how I could do this logic, for `InstrumentationRegistry`, because the methods are different.